# In Bootstrap v5.0.0-alpha1 what can I use for media (BS 3/4)?

Tags: javascript, html, css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-5

I want to use a media object in Bootstrap v5.0.0-alpha1, but how?

In Bootstrap 3 & 4, I'm using it like this:

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.5.2/css/bootstrap.min.css">

<div class="container mt-3">
<h2>Media Object</h2>
<p>Create a media object with the .media and .media-body classes:</p>
<div class="media border p-3">
    <img src="https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2016/11/18/23/38/child-1837375_960_720.png" alt="John Doe"
         class="mr-3 mt-3 rounded-circle" style="width:60px;">
    <div class="media-body">
        <h4>John Doe <small>Posted on February 19, 2016</small></h4>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et
            dolore magna aliqua.</p>
    </div>
</div>
</div>
```

In [v5.0.0-alpha1](https://v5.getbootstrap.com/), which class can I use for a media object? I was unable to find any class named 'media' in Bootstrap 5.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

In Bootstrap 5, the `.media` object has been removed. Instead, you can use the utility classes along with flexbox to create a similar layout.

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap/5.1.0/css/bootstrap.min.css"/>

<div class="container mt-3">
<h2>Media Object</h2>
<p>Create a media object without .media and .media-body classes (BS5):</p>
<div class="d-flex border p-3">
    <img src="https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2016/11/18/23/38/child-1837375_960_720.png" alt="John Doe"
         class="flex-shrink-0 me-3 mt-3 rounded-circle" style="width:60px;height:60px;">
    <div>
        <h4>John Doe <small>Posted on February 19, 2016</small></h4>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et
            dolore magna aliqua.</p>
    </div>
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: In BS 5, for margin and padding utilities, `mr` and `ml` and now `me` and `ms` (margin end and start)...

Answer (score 4):

Bootstrap 5's documentation illustrates how to use the Cards to achieve the old Media Object layout. https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.0/components/card/#horizontal

For example:

```
<div class="card mb-3 border-0">
    <div class="row g-3">
        <div class="col-md-4">
            <svg class="bd-placeholder-img" width="100%" height="250" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" role="img" aria-label="Placeholder: Image" preserveAspectRatio="xMidYMid slice" focusable="false"><title>Placeholder</title><rect width="100%" height="100%" fill="#868e96"></rect><text x="50%" y="50%" fill="#dee2e6" dy=".3em">Image</text></svg> 
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-8">
            <div class="card-body p-0">
                <h5 class="card-title">Card title</h5>
                <p class="card-text">This is a wider card with supporting text below as a natural lead-in to additional content. This content is a little bit longer.</p>
                <p class="card-text"><small class="text-muted">Last updated 3 mins ago</small></p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score -1):

For those of you who are just using the grid parts of Bootstrap, you could achieve a media object layout like this:

```
  <figure class="row">
    <p class="col-auto">
      <img src="https://placeimg.com/100/100/animals" alt="A cute animal">
    </p>
    <figcaption class="col">Look at the cute animal</figcaption>
  </figure>
```

`col-auto` shrink-wraps the column to the width of the content (in the above example, an image) and `col` simply takes up (or distributes, if there's more than one) the remaining space. [See the documentation](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.0/layout/grid/#variable-width-content), for more information.